# Why does the result array start with 0 rather than 1?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Shouldn't i be pushing 1 to my result array for the first iteration if start = 0?

```
function getEveryOtherNumber(start, end) {
    let resultArr = [];
    while (start < end) {
        resultArr.push(start++);
        start++;
    }
    return resultArr;
}

console.log(getEveryOtherNumber(0, 10)); // =>  [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

`start++` the postfix operator returns the value of start and then increments.

`++start` the prefix operator increments the value of start and then returns.

You are looking for the second one :)

Answer (score 2):

because start starts at 0, and `start++` assigns the value AFTER pushing.

if you want to do it before, use `++start`.